# How do I RDP to server and open Microsoft outlook

Tags: batch-file, outlook, windows-server-2008, wmi, remote-desktop

**Functionality:**
I have a server where Microsoft Outlook is configured/Rules defined in such a way that based on email received it run particular programs/scripts.

**Issue:** 
server is scheduled to reboot every week for maintenance. Every time it reboot I have to manually login to server and open Outlook to enable above functionality.

**Question:**
Is there any way in windows(program/command) using which I can automatically RDP to server and open outlook program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) utility from microsoft.

```
C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\remote-computer-name or IP address -u "username" -p "password" "path_to_outlook.exe_on remote_computer"
```

Example:

C:\temp\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\192.168.0.88 -u "Admin" -p mypass "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"

Comment: Hi, Can you please check below and help on this      
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203577/launch-notepad-exe-using-psexec-sysinternal-tool

Answer (score 0):

The above quote `C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\remote-computer-name or IP address -u "username" -p "password" "path_to_outlook.exe_on remote_computer"`requires you to be logged in to the server first. Otherwise it would launch Outlook but new emails would not be downloaded.